# Retrieve sAMAccountName of users in LDAP group

Tags: java, spring, security, ldap, spring-ldap

I need to retrieve `user_ids` (sAMAccountName) of a list of users under a LDAP group. I am using Spring security `org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate` with `org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper` implementation.

My search is:

`template.search(base, filter, new AttributesMapperImpl());`

My search (member of attribute) returns the name of the users 
`(CN=Lname\, Fname M,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=Users,OU=xx,DC=xx,DC=xxxxx,DC=xx)`. In order to get the sAMAccountName I have to turn around do another LDAP lookup.

Is there a way I could get sAMAccountName of users using a single lookup?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since the LDAP server is an Active Directory you could make use of the memberOf attribute in the search filter to retrieve users belonging to a specific group and set returning attribute as sAMAccountName.

(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=""))

Note that this is not a very efficient way.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why "this is not a very efficient way"? Why is it slow? What would be faster and achieve the same goal?